# Should I do migration testing if the new library needs a different testing suite?

Tags: unit-testing, migration

I'm using a pretty old library to make server requests which is not properly tested and it not really matching nowadays requirements, so the plan is to migrate to a new one over the next release. So the idea is to plan a migration testing suite in order to make the transition painless.

The thing is, the new library works in a completely different way, and the migration testing suite would apparently need to be fully changed (which makes the whole purpose of it a little bit less interesting).

**Does it make sense to have a migration testing suite, if the new library can't use that one?**

**Does it make sense to create an intermediate migration testing suite** *(if that's ever possible)* **which can't test everything properly, but can give us a sense of security?**

Comment: If the tests you're writing to validate the migration have to be changed due to the migration, they're the wrong tests.

Comment: @jonrsharpe lucky me, I haven't started with them yet. I've been investigating how to test over that library, and most say that the """probably only""" way to test it is with an instrumentation testing suite (not ideal at all), whether the new one has proper sockets to throw in a stub.

Comment: You don't test the lib. You test your code. First with the current lib, later with the new one. If tests changes, your application is too coupled to the lib. Fix that first.